# call soap service from Phonegap

Tags: jquery, web-services, cordova, soap

I tried every way on internet to call soap service with phonegap. But I cannot access to service. 
If anyone can help me I will realy be grateful.

This is my code(ı must hide some places because of customer rights):

http://pastebin.com/cRun5PRh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/kerrishotts/3786070 might help. This is *ancient* code, so I don't even know if it will work for you or not. It might give you a start, though.